# How to record the tick of a mechanical pocket watch?

Tags: audio-recording, recording

I'm talking about the slight ticking sound of a truly mechanical watch.

I've done some research, and I'm thinking of using a Cardioid Condenser Microphone along with a USB preamp and connecting that to my computer and recording it with something like Audacity.

Is this a good idea or am I way off? Are there specific microphone types you would suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You're not at all way off. This sounds like a very good place to start, however I would recommend using a small lavalier microphone with an appropriate computer interface. This will allow you to get the capsule much closer to the mechanism than you will be able to with the MXL770.

Comment: In addition : contact microphone as in https://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-Contact-Microphone/